# How do I specify a view for multiple platforms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, inheritance, xamarin

This is hard to put into words.

I have a `class LoginPage : Activity` which contains the usual View setup for Android like `OnCreate (Bundle bundle)` etc.

But since this is a cross-platform project, I would like to generalize the structure of my view for each platform (iOS, Windows), so I wrote a `public abstract class LoginPage` which just has methods like `abstract DoPageSetup()` and `abstract checkLogin()` etc.

**Problem:**
When I put that `abstract class LoginPage` into my Core Project (PCL), I can inherit it from my Android project, but since multiple inheritance is forbidden in C#, I can't also inherit from Activity, which I need.

Because at the end of the day, I will call this `LoginPage` like this from my `MainActivity`: `StartActivity(typeof(LoginPage));`

But the implemented `LoginPage` needs to follow the structure of my `abstract class` and inherit from `Activity`.

Comment: You have a bigger problem.  How are you expecting to run a C# application on Android?

Comment: That is not a problem with Xamarin.

Comment: Oh good.  Please mention that in your question and/or tag your question appropriately.

Comment: You might consider using delegation rather than inheritance.   If the LoginPage class doesn't know the details of the actual UI then it is probably the Model part of the MVC (or MPC) design pattern and the activity should have a reference to a LoginPage rather than "being" a LoginPage

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you please elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the word you're looking for is `interface`.

You won't be able to implement any methods in the interface definition, but you can declare them there.

```
public interface LoginPage {
  void doPageSetup();
  void checkLogin();
  //...
}
public class SpecificLoginPage : Activity, LoginPage {
  void doPageSetup() {
  }
  void checkLogin() {
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, that does work. I looked for an approach where I can partially implement the shared view class, hence I chose abstract.

Comment: Consider creating a `LoginPageDelegate` that handles the platform-agnostic code for you. You'll have to create an instance in each of your `SpecificLoginPage` classes, but writing a one line instantiation is cheaper than copying code around.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use two options.

1. If you want to share UI Code, consider using Xamarin.Forms.  Xamarin.Forms is a cross platform abstraction that allows you the develop your UI, and it will eventually use the native UI Elements per the platform.
2. Your second option is to use an MVVM pattern.  The MVVMCross framework is very popular and very powerful.  If you're not familiar with MVVM, look it up and it's a very powerful pattern to share code in cross platform applications (using MVVMCross).

Either option is going to depend on your requirements and there's really no right or wrong option.  It's going to depend on the platforms you're targeting and your goals for your apps.

Answer (score 0):

Saphire asked me to elaborate on this  comment:

> You might consider using delegation rather than inheritance. If the LoginPage class doesn't know the details of the actual UI then it is probably the Model part of the MVC (or MPC) design pattern and the activity should have a reference to a LoginPage rather than "being" a LoginPage

Model-View-Presenter (MVP) is a design pattern that is often appropriate for applications that have a User Interface The purpose is to separate the application into three roles which can be implemented relatively independently:]

- The role of the **View** is painting the screen and providing a place for the user to click or type.

  - Example: a text view into which a login Id can be typed.
  - In Android terms the View the Layout/ViewGroup containing nested Views.
- The role of the **Model** is to hold  the domain or business data:

  - Example: The login credentials and whether or not they are valid.
  - This is not platform-specific.  Login status happens on any platform you are running on.
- The role of the **Presenter** is to act as glue between the View and the Model.

  - When the user clicks the [login] button, the Activity (acting a a Presenter) fetches text from a view (without worrying what type of view it is) and sends a "User-wants-to-log-in-with-these-credentials" request to the LoginPage[Model].
  - When the LoginPage[Model] responds, OK, or DENIED, the Activity [Presenter] uses that information to update the appropriate elements in the the View, or maybe even launch a new Activity.

What I am suggesting is that since LoginPage is agnostic with respect to plaform, maybe it is serving the role of the Model.  I'll leave it to your judgement to determine whether the MVP pattern fits your design.

[This Wikipedia page:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)
provides a more elaborate explanation of Model-View-Presenter.